# How to obtain HttpServletRequest @Context in DropWizard Auth

Tags: dropwizard

I am using Basic Auth in Dropwizard 0.8
and I need to get access to the request context in my SimpleAuthenticator class, beyond the basic credentials.

Perhaps I need my own AuthFactory implementation to do this?

I want to implement basic access control for Basic Auth based on the resource path requested.

Thanks

Jon

Comment: No not yet, I'll be coming back to it again soon and have another go.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @PermitAll
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getResponse(**@Context** SecurityContext context) {
        SimplePrincipal principal = (SimplePrincipal)context.getUserPrincipal();

        return Response.ok("{\"Hello\": \"" + principal.getUsername() + "\"}").build();
    }
```

Using @Context  suffice for the basic Authorization atleast for Dropwizard version 0.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used 0.8, but in 0.9+, you can use `@Auth` and `@PermitAll` to control which resources have auth and which ones don't. Would that not satisfy your requirement? or you prefer a finer grained control?

Here's a changeset for auth in 0.9. You can refer to [Dropwizard: BasicAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671392/dropwizard-basicauth) for sample code.